# Sizing form to Control.Bounds.Bottom creates unexpected result

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form, in which I have a Tab Control in which I have other controls.

Since the amount of controls is dynamic and I want to size the Form just right I have this piece of code:

```
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        foreach (Control x in Tab_Control.Controls)
        {
            if (x.Bounds.Right > w) w = x.Bounds.Right;
            if (x.Bounds.Bottom > h) h = x.Bounds.Bottom;
        }
        Tab_Control.Size = new Size(w, h);
        Form1.Size = new Size(w, h);
```

While this sets the form width just right its height crops two controls on the bottom. I thought it might be because the positions are relative to the parent control, but when I used "PointToScreen(Point.Empty)" to get some real coordinates I found the difference to be 21 pixels, which didn't help much.

So I am wondering why setting the form height to h ends up being too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the ClientSize property instead.

Better yet is to write no code at all.  Set the form's AutoSize property to True, AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink.  You surely prefer setting the Margin property on control(s) at the bottom and the right so there's a decent space between the control and the border.

Comment: Setting the ClientSize worked, but setting "AutSize" to True and "AutoSizeMode" to "GrowAndShrink" crops some bottom controls (which have margins) for some reason.

Comment: Nvm, it doesn't work, because there is a Tab Control in it and it doesn't have an AutoSize propery, per se.

Answer (score 3):

The discrepancy is due to the size of the form's title bar.

You are calculating the size required by the controls correctly, but you are then setting the overall size of the window - which includes the title bar - to that height.

You'll need to add on the height of the title bar to the size you are calculating.

You can get the height of the title bar from the [`CaptionHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.captionheight(v=vs.110).aspx) property in [`System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation(v=vs.110).aspx)

If that doesn't cover all of the discrepancy then look at the form's border thickness to see if you need to take that into account as well

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little, but there is stil some cropping occuring. It still falls short.

Comment: @mathgenius - you'll probably need to take the border thickness into account as well. Check the numbers that are in the SystemInformation class.

Comment: So far adding the CaptionHeight, BorderSize.Height and Border3DSize.Height did not fully help. There's a good 20 pixels missing. I looked at all the members of "SystemInformation" but did not see any others that would be applicable to my case.